# CSS animation stretch element outside of parent container to fixed position

Tags: jquery, css

how can I "stretch" an element (that is, increasing its width with a keyframes animation) to a centered or fixed position outside of its parent container without having the element "jump"?

That's how it should look like (working example without parent container):

https://jsfiddle.net/4afbqdzp/

```js
$('.mytrigger').click(function(){
  $('.box').toggleClass('mybox');
})
```

```css
* { border: 1px solid blue !important; }

.row-height {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
}

@keyframes mykeyframe {
  50%, 100% {
    // position: fixed;
    width: 90vw;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);;
  }
  100% {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}


.mytrigger {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mybox {animation: mykeyframe 3s ease forwards;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="row row-height">
         <div class="col-12 text-center">
           <div class="mytrigger">click me</div>
           <div class="box"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the site I'm working on requires to have multiple containers which limit the width change of the element by the left borders of the container.

In the example below I changed the position of the element in the keyframe animation to "fixed", which allows me to add a "left: 10px" (based on the screen border, ignoring the parent container), but the problem with that solution is that the position change "jumps":

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lkj74rb/

```js
$('.mytrigger').click(function(){
  $('.box').toggleClass('mybox');
})
```

```css
* { border: 1px solid blue !important; }

.row-height {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
}

@keyframes mykeyframe {
  50%, 100% {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);;
  }
  100% {
    // width: 99vw;
    height: 50vh;
  }
}


.mytrigger {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}

.mybox {animation: mykeyframe 3s ease forwards;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row row-height">
         <div class="col-4 text-center"></div>
         <div class="col-4 text-center">
           <div class="mytrigger">click me</div>
           <div class="box"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-4 text-center"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.